# Данные из массива скачать в виде файла

Tags: php, jquery

Здравствуйте.

Каким образом можно передать данные из массива, чтобы клиент при нажатии на кнопку <kbd>скачать</kbd> мог получить массив в виде txt файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам пример для формата xlsx.

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="schedule.xlsx"');
echo $content;
```